# problema al contestar un tweet con imagen con tweepy (python)

Tags: python, api, tweepy

Mis amigos y yo hemos creado un bot de twitter, queremos que al mencionar el bot te responda con una foto y un texto. Para ello utilizo la función:

```
api.update_with_media(fr.fotochiste(posicion),'@' + mention.user.screen_name + fr.textochiste(posicion), mention.id)
```

Funcionar funciona bien, en el sentido de que envía el tweet con una foto y un texto mencionando al usuario. **El problema es que no crea el tweet como una respuesta a la mención correspondiente, sino que crea un tweet totalmente nuevo**. Pensé que el problema podía ser que no pillara bien el "mention.id", pero lo imprimí por pantalla en un intento y lo pilla perfectamente... Quizá esté entendiendo mal la documentación así que dejo una foto de la misma.

[image: Documentación api]

El código más extendido es el siguiente (todas las opciones funcionan perfectamente, contestando a los tweets de quien lo menciona, excepto la de enviar una foto con update_with_media):

```
#devuelve los tweets a partir del id del último tweet visto (ultimo_id)
mentions = api.mentions_timeline(ultimo_id, tweet_mode='extended')

for mention in reversed(mentions):
    print(str(mention.id) + ' - ' + mention.full_text)
    ultimo_id = mention.id
    guardar_ultimo_id(ultimo_id, FILE_NAME)

    #dar fav
    api.create_favorite(mention.id)

    #contestar en función de las palabras que haya en el tweet
    if 'poema' in mention.full_text.lower() or 'poemita' in mention.full_text.lower():
        api.update_status('@' + mention.user.screen_name + ' ' + fr.get_poema(), mention.id)

    elif 'piropo' in mention.full_text.lower() or 'piropito' in mention.full_text.lower():
        api.update_status('@' + mention.user.screen_name + ' ' + fr.get_piropo(), mention.id)
    #esto tb dice piropos pero lo he cambiado para que a Iñaki le saliera bien la jugada-->
    elif 'algo' in mention.full_text.lower() and 'bonito' in mention.full_text.lower():
        api.update_status('@' + mention.user.screen_name + ' ' + fr.get_piropo(), mention.id)

    elif 'curiosidad' in mention.full_text.lower() or 'curioso' in mention.full_text.lower():
        api.update_status('@' + mention.user.screen_name + ' ' + fr.get_curiosidad(), mention.id)

    elif 'chiste' in mention.full_text.lower():
        numerito = random.randint(0,2)
        if numerito == 1:
            api.update_status('@' + mention.user.screen_name + ' ' + fr.get_chiste(), mention.id)
        else:
            try:
                posicion = fr.numero_chiste()
                api.update_with_media(fr.fotochiste(posicion),'@' + mention.user.screen_name + fr.textochiste(posicion), mention.id)
            except:
                print("Algo no va bien")

    else:
        api.update_status('@' + mention.user.screen_name + ' ' + fr.get_frase_random(), mention.id)
```

Comment: Hola Andres, prueba usando: `api.update_status("my update", in_reply_to_status_id = tweetid)`
Esto me ha funcionado anteriormente. Revisa las respuestas de este post [9322465](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322465/reply-to-tweet-with-tweepy-python) donde tienes otras soluciones disponibles.